# transfer data into columns

Tags: text-processing, scripting

inputfile contains:

```
dn: cn=wss_savvion
cn: users
cn: avvionvc
owner: cn=SSC_admin
owner: uid=GNG2938427
```

dn: cn=Web_Admin, EN=OC1Test
cn: Administrators

dn: cn=sample1,
cn: TestPart1,Testpart2

Need Output file Like:

```
DN                          CN1                 CN2       OWNER            OWNER1           OWNER2      OWNER3
cn=wss_savvion              users               avvionvc  cn=SSC_admin     uid=GNG2938427
cn=Web_Admin, EN=OC1Test    Administrators
cn=sample1,                 TestPart1,Testpart2
```

As you see the above data is 3 sets, few set contains more cn, more owners. whenever there is more owners or cn available it needs to copied into Owner 1 or owner 2 .... and so on...

can somebody Help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on the Unix Stack Exchange, I'll assume your system runs Perl. The only dependency for this script is the Perl module 'Text::Table' which can be installed on most systems as:

```
cpan Text::Table
```

That being said, assuming that this file will always have the blocks of information seperated by an empty (no text) line, the script below works. I've tried to be more verbose than I usually am in this script, so you can try to understand what is going on or make modifications as you need to. The only requirement aside from the module is that you replace the line `my $file = '/path/to/inputfile'` with the actual path to your input file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Table;

my $file = '/path/to/inputfile';
my $table = process_file($file);
print $table;

sub process_file {
    my $file = shift;
    die "$file doesn't exist!" if ! -e $file;
    die "$file isn't readable" if ! -r $file;

    my @blocks;
    my $block = '';
    open(my $fh, "<", "$file") or die "Couldn't open $file: $!";
    while(<$fh>) {
        chomp $_;
        $block .= "$_\n" if $_ !~ /^\s*$/;
        if(($_ =~ m/^\s*$/ && $block ne '') || eof) {
            $block =~ s/\n$//g;
            push(@blocks, $block);
            $block = '';
        }
    }
    close $fh;

    my @rows; 
    my $max_cn = 0;    
    my $max_own = 0;
    foreach my $b (@blocks) {
        my %row = (
            'dn'    => '',
            'cn'    => [],
            'owner' => []
        );

        my @ba = split("\n", $b);
        for(@ba) {
            $_ =~ /^([a-z]+): (.+)$/;
            $row{dn} = $2 if $1 eq 'dn';
            push($row{cn}, $2) if $1 eq 'cn';
            push($row{owner}, $2) if $1 eq 'owner';
        }
        $max_cn = scalar @{$row{cn}} if $max_cn < @{$row{cn}};
        $max_own = scalar @{$row{owner}} if $max_own < @{$row{owner}};
        push(@rows, \%row);
    }

    my @headers = @{build_headers($max_cn, $max_own)};
    my $tb = Text::Table->new(@headers);
    my @inserts;
    foreach my $r (@rows) {
        push($r->{cn}, " ") until scalar @{$r->{cn}} == $max_cn;
        push($r->{owner}, " ") until scalar @{$r->{owner}} == $max_own;
        my @insert = ($r->{dn});
        push(@insert, $_) foreach @{$r->{cn}};
        push(@insert, $_) foreach @{$r->{owner}};
        push(@inserts, \@insert);
    }
    $tb->load(@inserts);
    return $tb;
}
sub build_headers {
    my $cn = shift;
    my $own = shift;
    my @headers = ("DN");
    for(my $i = 1; $i <= $cn; $i++) {
        push(@headers, "CN$i");
    }
    for(my $i = 1; $i <= $own; $i++) {
        push(@headers, "OWNER$i");
    }
    return \@headers;
}
```